# 1D case of Brouwer fixed-point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $I=[0,1]$ be the closed unit interval. Suppose $f$ is a continuous mapping of $I$ into $I$. Prove that $f(x)=x$ for at least one $x\in I$.

**Proof:** By contradiction. Let for any point $x\in I$ we have $f(x)\neq x$. Define $g(x):=f(x)-x$. Hence $g(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in I$ and is continuous on $I$. Also $0<|g(x)|\leqslant 1$. So we have four cases:

1. $g(0)<0$ and $g(1)>0$.
2. $g(0)>0$ and $g(1)<0$.
3. $g(0)>0$ and $g(1)>0$.
4. $g(0)<0$ and $g(1)<0$.

The first two cases leads us to contradiction by intermediate value theorem.

In case 3 we have that $g(1)>0$. Hence $f(1)>1$ and it's contradiction because $f:I\to I$. The same contradiction we get in last case.

Is my proof true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is certainly correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking!